# How can I print a NSMutable array in to a UILabel with a left to right format, and include spacing in between objects?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a calculator and in its controller i have a NSMutable array which stores objects. It's a RPN calculator so for example if I type 357 (Hit Enter), 589 (Hit operation key +), then objects are pushed into the array in this format: NSMutableArray *completeOperations([0]:357, [1]:589, [2]:+) - not sure if this is syntactically correct but I'm just trying to get the idea across. So what I want to do is print this array into the UILabel, property: fullPerformDisplay, in the format 357 589 + =. As shown I need to add spaces in between the objects when I print them and it need to print in a left to right format.

Comment: RPN Calculator and displaying the stack reminds me of CS193P course from Stanford University... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are in an array you can join the components of an array and convert it to a string with [NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray withObjects: @"357", @"589", @"+", nil];
NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
// string will contain @"357 589 +"

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = string;
```